# Change all opacity values of a CSS color pattern by a certain ratio

Tags: javascript, css, regex, rgba

So we have this string representing a color pattern in CSS:

```
const COLOR = 'linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3), purple, rgba(100, 100, 200), rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8))';
```

It is possible that we may have more rgba(....) or even rgb(...) substrings.

Is there an efficient regexp or method to increase the opacity value of each **rgba()** substrings that have the opacity specified by 10% for example?

```
function changeOpacity(text, change = 1) {

    ...

    return(newTextValue);
}

console.log(changeOpacity(COLOR, 1.1));
```

So the resulting value would be:

```
linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.33), purple, rgba(100, 100, 200), rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.88))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const COLOR = 'linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3), purple, rgba(100, 100, 200), rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8))';

function changeOpacity(text, change = 1) {
    newstr = text.replace(/\d\.\d/g, x => (parseFloat(x) * change).toFixed(2));
    return(newstr);
}

console.log(changeOpacity(COLOR, 1.1));
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your exact requirement but you can easily change the opacity of rgba(....) or rgb(....) in a gradient.

linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3), purple 40%, rgba(100, 100, 200) 50%, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8))